# Why starting a Application Server in DEBUG mode expensive

Tags: java, debugging, application-server, debug-mode

What makes starting a Application Server (any piece of software for that matter) in DEBUG mode expensive? Would it not be liberty to be able to hook on to a production box and be able to walk through the code? What is the price that we pay if a application is started in DEBUG mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEBUG mode is primarily intended for development and to find root cause of any issue (in dev phase or later). It's not what we do in production. Apart from it, below are few practical issues we may face in debug mode:

- If you place too many debug points, application building get too
  slow, eventually halt.
- Consider a case if someone forget debug points on PROD, users will not be         able to proceed.